# Converting a Spark Dataframe to a mutable Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, apache-spark, dataframe, collections

I am new to spark and scala. I am trying to query a table in hive(select 2 columns from the table) and convert the resulting dataframe into a Map. I am using Spark 1.6 with Scala 2.10.6.

Ex:

```
Dataframe:
+--------+-------+
| address| exists|
+--------+-------+
|address1|   1   |
|address2|   0   |
|address3|   1   |
+--------+-------+ 
should be converted to: Map("address1" -> 1, "address2" -> 0, "address3" -> 1)
```

This is the code I am using:

```
val testMap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Any] = Map()
val df= hiveContext.sql("select address,exists from testTable")
qualys.foreach( r => {
  val key = r(0).toString
  val value = r(1)
  testMap+=(key -> value)
  }
)
testMap.foreach(println)
```

When I run the above code, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

It is throwing this error at the line where I am trying to add the key value pair to the Map. i.e. `testMap+=(key -> value)`

I know that there is a better and simpler way of doing this using the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map`. However, I am using Spark 1.6 and I don't think this function is available. I tried doing the `import` and I didn't find it in the list of available functions.

why is my approach giving me an error? and is there a better/elegant way of achieving this with spark 1.6?

any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I changed the way the elements are being added to the Map to the following:     `testMap.put(key, value)`.

I was previously using the `+=` for adding the elements. Now i don't get the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` anymore. However, no elements are getting added to the `testMap`. After the foreach step is complete, I tried to print the size of the map and all the elements in it and I see that there are `zero` elements.

Why are the elements not getting added? I am also open to any other better approach. Thank you!!

Comment: oh, if that's what you need, `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map` is irrelevant anyway. You just need to convert to `RDD[(String, Int)]` and use `collectAsMap()`. You can find posts about how to convert a DataFrame into RDD.

Comment: That seems like an easy way! But, the result will be an immutable Map right? How do I change it to a Mutable one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042878/how-can-i-convert-immutable-map-to-mutable-map-in-scala

Comment: You're awesome! Please post your comments as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be broken down into 3 steps, each one already solved on SO:

1. Convert DataFrame to `RDD[(String, Int)]`
2. Call `collectAsMap()` on that RDD to get an immutable map
3. Convert that map into a mutable one (e.g. as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5050653/5344058))

**NOTE**: I don't know why you need a *mutable* map - it's worth noting that using a *mutable* collection rarely makes much sense in Scala. Sticking with immutable objects only is safer and easier to reason about. "Forgetting" about the existence of mutable collections makes learning functional APIs (like Spark's!) much easier.

Comment: I was wondering if you can help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445328/adding-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe-by-using-the-values-of-multiple-other-columns 
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

simply you can collect the data from dataframe and iterate on top of it, it will work

```
qualys.collect.map( r => {
val key = r(0).toString
val value = r(1)
testMap+=(key -> value)
 }
)
```