# Adding a new column to a Dataframe by using the values of multiple other columns in the dataframe - spark/scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark SQL and Dataframes. I have a `Dataframe` to which I should be adding a new column based on the values of other columns. I have a `Nested IF` formula from excel that I should be implementing (for adding values to the new column), which when converted into programmatic terms, is something like this:

```
if(k =='yes')
{
  if(!(i==''))
  {
    if(diff(max_date, target_date) < 0)
    {
      if(j == '')
      {
        "pending" //the value of the column
      }
      else {
        "approved" //the value of the column
      }
    }
    else{
      "expired" //the value of the column
    }
  }
  else{
    "" //the value should be empty
  }
}
else{
  "" //the value should be empty
}
```

`i,j,k are three other columns in the Dataframe.` I know we can use `withColumn` and `when` to add new columns based on other columns, but I am not sure how I can achieve the above logic using that approach.

what would be an easy/efficient way to implement the above logic for adding the new column? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: where do max_date and target_date come from?

Comment: ‘Max_date’ comes from the table that I get my dataframe from. ‘Target_date’ is one of the three columns, i,j,k.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing, lets simplify that if statement:

```
if(k == "yes" && i.nonEmpty)
  if(maxDate - targetDate < 0)
    if (j.isEmpty) "pending" 
    else "approved"
  else "expired"
else ""
```

Now there are 2 main ways to accomplish this

1. Using a custom UDF
2. Using spark built in functions: `coalesce`, `when`, `otherwise`

#### Custom UDF

Now due to the complexity of your conditions, it will be rather tricky to do number 2. Using a custom UDF should suit your needs.

```
def getState(i: String, j: String, k: String, maxDate: Long, targetDate: Long): String =  
  if(k == "yes" && i.nonEmpty)
    if(maxDate - targetDate < 0)
      if (j.isEmpty) "pending" 
      else "approved"
    else "expired"
  else ""

val stateUdf = udf(getState _)
df.withColumn("state", stateUdf($"i",$"j",$"k",lit(0),lit(0)))
```

Just change lit(0) and lit(0) to your date code, and this should work for you.

#### Using spark built in functions

If you notice performance issues, you can switch to using `coalesce`, `otherwise`, and `when`, which would look something like this:

```
val isApproved = df.withColumn("state", when($"k" === "yes" && $"i" =!= "" && (lit(max_date) - lit(target_date) < 0) && $"j" =!= "", "approved").otherwise(null))
val isPending = isApproved.withColumn("state", coalesce($"state", when($"k" === "yes" && $"i" =!= "" && (lit(max_date) - lit(target_date) < 0) && $"j" === "", "pending").otherwise(null)))
val isExpired = isPending.withColumn("state", coalesce($"state", when($"k" === "yes" && $"i" =!= "" && (lit(max_date) - lit(target_date) >= 0), "expired").otherwise(null)))
val finalDf = isExpired.withColumn("state", coalesce($"state", lit("")))
```

I've used custom udf's in the past with large input sources without issues, and custom udfs can lead to much more readable code, especially in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Will give this a try once I get the chance. Will let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Hello. in your answer Using spark built-in functions, what does the `finalDF` statement mean? we're already putting `NULL` wherever the conditions are not met, right?

Comment: @Hemanth the coalesce function returns the first non null value. So if the current value of the state column is still null by the time all the previous conditions have been tried, then the value of the state column will be set to empty string.

Comment: I actually can substitute `NULL` for empty values. Also, the i, j values can be checked for `NULL` instead of empty values. Can I achieve the same with the below piece of code?

Comment: `DF2 = DF.withColumn("state", when(col("k") === 1 && col("i") != "NULL" &&(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.parse(maxPartitionDate.trim), LocalDate.parse(col("i").toString.trim)) < 0) && col("j") != "NULL", "approved").when(col("k") === 1  && col("i") != "NULL" && (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.parse(maxPartitionDate.trim), LocalDate.parse(col("i").toString.trim)) < 0) && col("j") == "NULL", "pending") .when(col("k") === 1  && col("i") != "NULL" && (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.parse(maxPartitionDate.trim), LocalDate.parse(col("i").toString.trim)) >= 0), "expired").otherwise(null))`

Comment: I am having trouble with using the `$ "col_name"` notation. Should I be importing a class for using that notation?

Comment: can you please take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47503696/casting-a-column-datatype-to-a-string-spark-scala 
@soote