# How to use non-column value in UserDefinedFunction (UDF) for adding a column to a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a simple dataframe I want to operate on:

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|   a|
|  2|   b|
|  3|   c|
|  4|   d|
|  5|   e|
+---+----+
```

I'm trying to add another column based on the "id" column and a value I'll pass through (in this case, the String "hey") when I call withColumn().

According to this other StackOverflow post ([Adding a new column to a Dataframe by using the values of multiple other columns in the dataframe - spark/scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445328/adding-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe-by-using-the-values-of-multiple-other-columns?rq=1)), I should be able to use UDFs, UserDefinedFunctions, however I get a "not applicable" error on the UDF call from IntelliJ with the code below

```
val table = Seq(("1", "a"), ("2", "b"), ("3", "c"), ("4", "d"), ("5", "e")).toDF("id", "name")

def newID(s: String, v: String): String = {
  s.concat("-" + v)
}

val newUDF = udf(newID _)

table.show()
val v = "hey"
val newO = table.withColumn("someOp", newUDF($"id", v)) // this works if I
// use the column "name" instead of the String v which looks
// like -> newUDF($"id", $"name")

newO.show()
```

So, I can get:

```
+---+----+------+
| id|name|someOp|
+---+----+------+
|  1|   a|   1-a|
|  2|   b|   2-b|
|  3|   c|   3-c|
|  4|   d|   4-d|
|  5|   e|   5-e|
+---+----+------+
```

but not:

```
+---+----+--------+
| id|name|  someOp|
+---+----+--------+
|  1|   a|   1-hey|
|  2|   b|   2-hey|
|  3|   c|   3-hey|
|  4|   d|   4-hey|
|  5|   e|   5-hey|
+---+----+--------+
```

Comment: I don't really understand the direct correlation here. Could you explain it? @user6910411

Comment: You have to turn your scala variable into a constant column with `lit`  like this:  `table.withColumn("someOp", newUDF($"id", lit(v))).show` (you must `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._)`